# Android deserialize String to a JSONObject without using libraries

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to convert a JSON that has been serialised to a String, back to a JSONObject, without having to install additional libraries.

I have this JSON:

```
{
  "asd": false,
  "qwe": false,
  "zxc": false,
  "qaxz": false,
  "asdqwe": false,
  "asdqwe": false,
  "wexd": false
}
```

Embedded as a String into another JSON object ("user") , by the name "app_settings"

Then I try this:

```
JSONObject settings = user.getJSONObject(JSONKeys.USER_SETTINGS);
```

Here is the exception that I get:

```
    06-20 12:15:19.105: W/System.err(17085):
 org.json.JSONException: Value {"asd":false,"qwe":false,"zxc":false,"qaxz":false,"asdqwe":false,"asdqwe":false,"wexd":false}
 at app_settings of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

**SOLUTION**

Changed:

```
JSONObject settings = user.getJSONObject(JSONKeys.USER_SETTINGS);
```

to

```
JSONObject settings = new JSONObject(user.getString(JSONKeys.USER_SETTINGS));
```

and it worked

Comment: What are "additional" libraries?

Comment: Let me get this clear, user is another JSONObject, this usr jsonobject has a key value pair with key=app_settings and value equal to the jsonobject you have mentioned. You want to store this jsonobject in another jsonobject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply do

`JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(your_string)`

Comment: I did that but I get an exception. I will paste it in the question

Comment: when you convert this into json, does it throw exception

Comment: changed JSONObject settings = user.getJSONObject(JSONKeys.USER_SETTINGS); to JSONObject settings = new JSONObject(user.getString(JSONKeys.USER_SETTINGS)); and fixed my problem

Answer (score 2):

There is a [constructor](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject%28java.lang.String%29) which takes a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

In so far as JSONObject library is already included in your Android project, you can simply use

```
JSONObject j = new JSONObject(YOUR STRING);
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than doing

```
JSONObject settings = new JSONObject(user.getString(JSONKeys.USER_SETTINGS));
```

I guess you can use

```
JSONObject settings = user.getJSONObject(JSONKeys.USER_SETTINGS);
```

So as to avoid unnecessary json->string->json parsing.